# Nested filters in angular for hierarchical data model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an hierarchical data model with lines of products and then sublines, and then sublines of sublines etc. What I am trying to do is isolate only the sublines that are directly descendants (sons not grandchildren) of a particular line or subline.

Here is my existing data model:

```
items:[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "description": "sth1",
    "name": "smname1",
    "level_type": "line",
    "ancestor": "",
    "descendant": "smname2"
   }
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "description": "sth2",
    "name": "smname1",
    "level_type": "subline",
    "ancestor": "smname1",
    "descendant": ""
    }
  },
]
```

Also for the example above another thing I'm trying to accomplish is to get the children of all the product lines. What I have tried but is not working so far is:

**Controller**

```
$scope.prodClassIsALine = function(item) {
        return item.level_type=='line';
    };

    $scope.prodClassIsASubLineof = function(item) {
        return item.ancestor==$scope.prodClassIsALine.name;
};
```

Tragic proposal just to show you that I need all children of all lines i.e. all items with ancestor names of items that are lines.

**Html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items  | filter:prodClassIsALine:prodClassIsASubLineof"> 
  <p>{[{item.name}]}</p>
</div>
```

Is this the way we are nesting filters in AngularJS? It seems that filters are iterating over the list that are given as attribute but further than that I can't understand in detail how they work. Please help.

**Solution**

**In script.js**

```
//product is my ng-module
//filter to get all product classes that are lines
product.filter('prodClassIsALine', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var out = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].level_type=='line') {
            out.push(input[i])
        };
      };
      return out;
    };
});

//filter to get all children of product classes that are lines
product.filter('prodClassLineChild', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var out = [];
      var out2 = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].level_type=='line') {
            out2.push(input[i])
        };
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < out2.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (input[j].ancestor==out2[i].name) {
                out.push(input[j])
            };
        };
      };
      return out;
    };
});
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items  | prodClassIsALine"> 
<!-- or <div ng-repeat="item in items  | prodClassLineChild"-->
  <p>{[{item.name}]}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do u mean this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items  | filter1 | filter2">
```

more info here
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.using_filters

EDIT:

now i got that u didnt wrote filters but scope function, u need something like this

```
myModule.filter('iif', function () {
    return function (input, trueValue, falseValue) {
        return input ? trueValue : falseValue;
    };
});
```

my use is class="{{ catalogItem.IS_FINAL | iif : 'IsFinalCatalogItem' : '' }}"

should look like this

```
myModule.filter('prodClassIsALine', function() {
    return function(item) {
        return item.level_type=='line';
    };
});
```

p.s. in angular 1.2 they added the standard iif syntax

Comment: <span  ng-repeat="item in items  | filter:prodClassIsALine | filter:prodClassIsASubLineof"> does not work however.

Comment: Thanks for your help bresleveloper